# How to intercalate questions with the response options in a cloze item (Moodle)?

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

Is it possible to intercalate questions with the response options in a cloze item (Moodle)?

Example:

From this:

[image]

to this:

question 1.

options (question 1)

question 2.

options (question 2)

and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by putting `##ANSWER1##` and `##ANSWER2##` etc. tags in the places where the interaction elements should be placed. In R/Markdown the hashtags have to be escaped: `\#\#Answer1\#\#` etc. A minimal example is included below. A more elaborate statistical example is: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/boxhist2/

```
Question
========
Which of these letters is a vowel?

\#\#ANSWER1\#\#

What is the first two-digit prime number?

\#\#ANSWER2\#\#

Answerlist
----------
* A
* B
* C
* 

Meta-information
================
exname: cloze
extype: cloze
exclozetype: schoice|num
exsolution: 100|11
```

This is rendered in Moodle like this:

[image: cloze]